# Best Resource for learning MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, github, npm

I started this question from a problem I was having following a tutorial(listed below). Some people felt it wasn't a good enough question. So I am re-stating my question.

What is the best resource for learning & understanding the MEAN Stack?

////Old post

Alright, I am at ends with this. I'm following this [tutorial](http://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/introduction-to-the-mean-stack-part-one-setting-up-your-tools/) and I've gotten to the point where I need to fork a project on github[done] and run npm install. thiss is what the directions say:

> At this point, you’ve done essentially all you need to do to run a MEAN stack application. You can simply clone/fork https://github.com/vkarpov15/mean-stack-skeleton , start a “mongod” process, navigate to the git repo, and run npm install -d

So what the hell does that mean? Navigate to the git repo and then run a command. Mongod is running, I'm in another shell session...now what?

thanks, I've been digging into this for a day now.

Comment: a whole day for that? it would be easier if you just read some basic tutorials about git/npm/node.js/mongodb, just the basics nothing more would prepare you to develop an app.

Comment: I would recommend the MongoDB free online course for Node.js developers. It goes through all of this at the beginning. https://university.mongodb.com/courses/10gen/M101JS/2014_March/about One started two days ago.

Comment: Alright, why -1. I was following a tutorial, it's not my fault it wasn't comprehensive enough. @JohnBarça, Thank you for pointing me to a good resource.

Comment: @JohnBarça submit your response as an answer and I will give you credit. Thanks

Comment: @Jason Spick. I added my comment to my original answer. Thanks and enjoy the MongoDB course -- I have done a couple and they are well put together, imho.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend the MongoDB free online course for Node.js developers, see:  [MongoDB/nodeJS course](https://university.mongodb.com/courses). It goes through all of this at the beginning. They repeat these courses every few months.

Answer to original question: It means go to the directory that was created when you ran git clone, in which you will find the package.json file.
The node package manager (npm) will parse the contents of package.json and download any other required dependencies -- in this case Express, MongoDB, Mongoose, Jade, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a tutorial for beginners that demonstrates how to build an enterprise-style app covering (installation, server, database, client):

[MEAN Stack Tutorial](http://www.bradoncode.com/tutorials/learn-mean-stack-tutorial)

Disclosure: I wrote the tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

I used many different resources. Since there are four components to the stack:

Angular:

1. Lynda.com "Ray Villalobos" does a great job going over angular.
2. Codeschool.com they have two good courses on angular, one is free.
3. Pluralisight.com They have a good intro course and more in-depth courses I still refer to.

Node.js:

1. Codeschool.com has a good course on node that cleared up a lot of questions.

Express

1. Codeschool.com also has a great course on this
2. Lynda.com "Ray Villalobos" has a good course featuring express

Mongo

1. MongoDb has a good amount of tutorials through youtube

https://scotch.io/ was also a great resource and starting point for me for the entire stack.
They also have an online book on the MEAN stack.

Answer (score 2):

Prerequisite for learning MEAN is to know MongoDB, Express.js, Angular.js and Node.js.

The best place to start learning MEAN Stack is to install sample MEAN application.
MEAN website(http://learn.mean.io/) provides step by step procedure to install mean application. The MEAN Website also explains the various folders inside the application in easy steps. I personally think MEAN website(http://learn.mean.io/) provides comprehensive documentation to understand MEAN.

If you are want to learn the MEAN through books. Please find list of books for learning MEAN

1. Getting MEAN with Mongo, Express, Angular, and Node by  Simon Holmes
2. MEAN Web Development by  Amos Q. Haviv Full Stack JavaScript
3. Development With MEAN by  Colin J Ihrig

Comment: Links are dead.